# SOAP request works in SOAPUI but fails in Python using Requests library

Tags: python, web-services, soap, python-requests, soapui

I am facing an issue while making a SOAP request from my Python code. I tested the same request using SOAP UI, and it worked successfully. However, when I tried to replicate the request in Python using the Requests library, it didn't work

> (I should add that I have already made other requests that worked both
> in SOAP UI and Python, but none of them involved a bearer token)

first i pass the wsdl is:

```
import requests
endpoint = "https://externalchannels-pro- 
ws.gruposancorseguros.com/Brokers/Document/DocumentService.svc?wsdl"
```

then i pass  the body and bearer token:

```
auth="""Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIn..."""
    
body="""<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:san="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SancorSeguros.Services.Contract.Document" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <soap:Header>
       </soap:Header>
       <soap:Body>
          <tem:GetCertificateDocument>
             <tem:request>
                <san:Branch>1500</san:Branch>
                <san:CertificatNumber>2</san:CertificatNumber>
                <san:Document>ConstanciaPolizaArgentina</san:Document>
                <san:OfficialNumber>349947</san:OfficialNumber>
                <san:ReferenceNumber>264448</san:ReferenceNumber>
             </tem:request>
          </tem:GetCertificateDocument>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>"""
```

Then i make the request:

```
headers = {"content-Type": 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://tempuri.org/IDocumentService/GetCertificateDocument"', 
                   "Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate",
                   "Accept":"*/*",
                   "Connection":"Keep-Alive",
                   "Host":"externalchannels-pro-ws.gruposancorseguros.com",
                   "Authorization":auth
                   } 
           
response = requests.request("POST", url=endpoint, data=body, headers=headers)
      
print(response)
print(response.content)
```

This returns:

```
>>> print(response)
<Response [500]>
>>> print(response.content)
b'<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><s:Body><s:Fault><s:Code><s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value></s:Code><s:Reason><s:Text xml:lang="en-US">No es posible finalizar la operaci\xc3\xb3n, favor intentar nuevamente. Activity: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</s:Text></s:Reason></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>'
```

I used httptoolkit to compare the requests and noticed that SOAP UI adds some lines to the SOAP request. I added the same to my Python code, but it resulted in a different error.

```
import requests

endpoint = "https://externalchannels-pro-ws.gruposancorseguros.com/Brokers/Document/DocumentService.svc"

auth="""Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiI..."""

body="""<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:san="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SancorSeguros.Services.Contract.Document" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <wsa:Action soap:mustUnderstand="1">
      http://tempuri.org/IDocumentService/GetCertificateDocument
    </wsa:Action>
    <wsa:To soap:mustUnderstand="1">
      https://externalchannels-pro-ws.gruposancorseguros.com/Brokers/Document/DocumentService.svc
    </wsa:To>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <tem:GetCertificateDocument>
      <tem:request>
        <san:Branch>
          1500
        </san:Branch>
        <san:CertificatNumber>
          2
        </san:CertificatNumber>
        <san:Document>
          ConstanciaPolizaArgentina
        </san:Document>
        <san:OfficialNumber>
          349947
        </san:OfficialNumber>
        <san:ReferenceNumber>
          264448
        </san:ReferenceNumber>
      </tem:request>
    </tem:GetCertificateDocument>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""



#session = requests.session()
headers = {"content-Type": 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://tempuri.org/IDocumentService/GetCertificateDocument"', 
           "Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate",
           "Accept":"*/*",
           "Connection":"Keep-Alive",
           "Host":"externalchannels-pro-ws.gruposancorseguros.com",
           "SOAPAction": "",
           "Authorization":auth
           } 
#headers.update({"Content-Length": str(len(body))})
#headers.update({"Authorization": auth})


response = requests.request("POST", url=endpoint, data=body, headers=headers)


print(response)
print(response.content)
```

the error:

```
>>> print(response)
>>> print(response)
<Response [500]>
>>> print(response.content)
b'<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action></s:Header><s:Body><s:Fault><s:Code><s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value></s:Code><s:Reason><s:Text xml:lang="en-US">No es posible finalizar la operaci\xc3\xb3n, favor intentar nuevamente. Activity: 0c295990-f194-4b68-86ef-50ee24763381</s:Text></s:Reason></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>'
```

I compared the requests again and confirmed that the bearer token and the code match. I suspect that SOAP UI may have some mechanism to verify the token correctly, but I haven't been able to figure it out. I would appreciate any assistance as I have been struggling with this issue for several days.

**This Are the soapui request working headers:**

1. **METHOD:POST**
2. **URL:**https://externalchannels-pro-ws.gruposancorseguros.com/Brokers/Document/DocumentService.svc

   **HEADERS**
3. **accept-encoding:** gzip,deflate
4. **authorization:** Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Ik1EWTVPVGc1TVRrek1FUkVRVVF4TVVZNE16WTJPVUkxTmpGQk5FUTRPVE14TnpNelJUVkRRZyJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1pY2Flb....truncated
   for security reasons
5. **connection:** Keep-Alive
6. **content-length:** 1026
7. **content-type:** application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://tempuri.org/IDocumentService/GetCertificateDocument"
8. **host:** externalchannels-pro-ws.gruposancorseguros.com
9. **user-agent:** Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)

---

**This are the not working python request headers:**

1. **METHOD:** POST
2. **URL** https://externalchannels-pro-ws.gruposancorseguros.com/Brokers/Document/DocumentService.svc

   **HEADERS**
3. **accept-encoding:** gzip,deflate
4. **authorization:** Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Ik1EWTVPVGc1TVRrek1FUkVRVVF...truncated
   for security reasons
5. **connection:** Keep-Alive
6. **content-length:** 940
7. **content-type:** application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://tempuri.org/IDocumentService/GetCertificateDocument"
8. **host:** externalchannels-pro-ws.gruposancorseguros.com
9. **user-agent:** python-requests/2.30.0

Comment: Hi. Please format your question according to these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend found the problem. It seems that Python was passing the body of the request with spaces between the parameters. After removing them, the request worked.

Before:

```
 <tem:GetCertificateDocument>
      <tem:request>
        <san:Branch>
                          1500
            
            
        </san:Branch>
        <san:CertificatNumber>
          2
        </san:CertificatNumber>
        <san:Document>
          ConstanciaPolizaArgentina
            
        </san:Document>
        <san:OfficialNumber>
          349947
        </san:OfficialNumber>
        <san:ReferenceNumber>
          264448
        </san:ReferenceNumber>
      </tem:request>
    </tem:GetCertificateDocument>
```

Working one:

```
<tem:GetCertificateDocument>
      <tem:request>
        <san:Branch>
          1500
        </san:Branch>
        <san:CertificatNumber>
          2
        </san:CertificatNumber>
        <san:Document>
          ConstanciaPolizaArgentina
        </san:Document>
        <san:OfficialNumber>
          349947
        </san:OfficialNumber>
        <san:ReferenceNumber>
          264448
        </san:ReferenceNumber>
      </tem:request>
    </tem:GetCertificateDocument>
```